# How do I add string values from List to DataFrame and recreate DF?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame and list like below.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'player_id': [298, 118, 108, 109, 168, 198, 116], 
                   'date': ['2018-06-22', '2018-06-23', '2018-07-24', '2018-07-25', 
                            '2019-06-22', '2019-06-25', '2019-07-25'], 
                   'score': [-2, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 6]})
df.head()
player_id   date        score
298     2018-06-22      -2
118     2018-06-23      1
108     2018-07-24      2
109     2018-07-25      3
168     2019-06-22      7


L = ['ab','da','Ae','gf']
```

I want to create a single data frame with all of the values in the list.
For ex: if I select 'ab' I want to add that to the above df and create a column as a "newName"

This is what I'm doing right now.

```py
for x in range(len(L)):
    print(L[x])
    df = df.append({'newName': L[x]}, ignore_index=True)
    
df
player_id   date        score   newName
298.0       2018-06-22  -2.0    NaN
118.0       2018-06-23  1.0     NaN
108.0       2018-07-24  2.0     NaN
109.0       2018-07-25  3.0     NaN
168.0       2019-06-22  7.0     NaN
198.0       2019-06-25  8.0     NaN
116.0       2019-07-25  6.0     NaN
NaN         NaN         NaN     ab
NaN         NaN         NaN     ac
NaN         NaN         NaN     da
NaN         NaN         NaN     gf

But I want to create something like this
player_id   date        score   newName
298.0       2018-06-22  -2.0    ab
118.0       2018-06-23  1.0     ab
108.0       2018-07-24  2.0     ab
109.0       2018-07-25  3.0     ab
168.0       2019-06-22  7.0     ab
198.0       2019-06-25  8.0     ab
116.0       2019-07-25  6.0     ab

next, I want to select the next item in the list and add it to the data frame

player_id   date        score   newName
298.0       2018-06-22  -2.0    ab
118.0       2018-06-23  1.0     ab
108.0       2018-07-24  2.0     ab
109.0       2018-07-25  3.0     ab
168.0       2019-06-22  7.0     ab
198.0       2019-06-25  8.0     ab
116.0       2019-07-25  6.0     ab
298.0       2018-06-22  -2.0    da
118.0       2018-06-23  1.0     da
108.0       2018-07-24  2.0     da
109.0       2018-07-25  3.0     da
168.0       2019-06-22  7.0     da
198.0       2019-06-25  8.0     da
116.0       2019-07-25  6.0     da

Like that need to add all the list objects
```

Is this possible to do it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: A side note: `for x in range(len(L)):` should just be `for x in L:`. If you're iterating over the elements in the list, just iterate the elements directly for the sake of simplicity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

```py
df_result = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)
for val in L:
    print(val)
    df['newName'] = val
    df_result = df_result.append(df, ignore_index=True)

df_result
```